# calculate the final concentration of this equation

Tags: stoichiometry

A student mixed 260ml of 1.2 M lead(II) nitrate with 300ml of 1.90M potassium iodide. What is the final concentration of $\ce{NO3^{-}}$ ?

the answer is 1.11M , but he used the moles of lead(II) nitrate to find out the moles of $\ce{NO3^{-}}$ ,, and I think he should had used the moles of potassium iodide since it is the limiting reactant.

could anyone explain ?

Comment: Is the concept of the limiting reagent reagent useful here? Actually, you are looking at a spectator ion, that does not participate in the precipitation but remains in solution!

Comment: Related: [What does Pb(NO₃)₂ + KI form?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-does-pbno%E2%82%83%E2%82%82-ki-form)

Answer (score 1):

> […] he should had used the moles of potassium iodide since it is the limiting reactant.

- Did any reaction take place upon mixing solutions of $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ and $\ce{KI}$?
- If so, did the reaction change the number of moles of $\ce{NO3-}$ in solution by precipitation, oxidation, reduction, etc.?
- Would the result of the calculation be different if just 300 mL of water were added to the $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ solution?

**Update I**

Now for the rocket science (solubilities at 20 °C):

\begin{array}{cr}
\mathrm{compound} & \mathrm{solubility\ [g\cdot L^{-1}]} \\ \hline
\ce{Pb(NO3)2} & 522\\ 
\ce{KI} & 1430\\
\ce{KNO3} & 316\\
\ce{PbI2} & 0.76\\
\end{array}

The rather low solubility of $\ce{PbI2}$ suggests that on combination of the two solutions, the following may happen:

$$\ce{Pb^{2+} + 2 NO3- + 2 K+ + 2 I- -> 2 K+ + 2 NO3- + PbI2 v}$$

So again:

1. Does this in any way change the absolute amount of  $\ce{NO3-}$ **in solution**?
2. What does change for the concentration of $\ce{NO3-}$ when 300 mL of another solution is added to 260ml of 1.2 M $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ solution?

**Update II**

- Initial $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ solution

> 260 mL of a 1.2M solution of $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ contain $1.2\ \mathrm{\frac{mol}{L}}\ \cdot\ 2\cdot\ 0.26\ \mathrm{L} = 0.624\ \mathrm{mol}\ \ce{NO3-}$

- After mixing

> Addition of 300 mL of the $\ce{KI}$ solution results in the precipitation of $\ce{PbI2}$, but **does not change the absolute amount** of  $\ce{NO3-}$ in solution. However, it **changes the total volume** and hence the concentration, which calculates to $\frac{0.624\ \mathrm{mol}}{(0.26 + 0.3) \mathrm{L}} = 1.11 \ M$